# Hiding HTML using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[I want to create a multistep modal using this](https://github.com/ngzhian/multi-step-modal)

The problem is that **my modal is not in steps** but instead **it's in all in the same page**.

This works if I put the html directly but doesn't when I create this dinamically. I think it has something to do with being javascript generated. What am I missing here?

Please check the html structure of the link I provided.

```js
$("body").on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(e) {

  var testCaseNames = ['test1', 'test2'];
  var inputs = ['test3', 'test4'];

  //Modal
  var modal = '<form class="modal multi-step" id="creationModal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"></div><div class="modal-step-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"></div></div></form>';
  
   $('#modalDiv').empty().append(modal);
  
  $.each(testCaseNames, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
    console.log(inputs);
    //Headers
    $('.modal-header').append('<h4 class="modal-title step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '">' + value + '</h4>');
    //Body
    $('.modal-step-body').append('<div class="modal-body step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '"></div>');
    $.each(inputs, function(index, input) {
      console.log(input);
      $(".modal-body.step.step-" + key).append(input);
    });
    //Footer Buttons
    $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>');
    $('.modal-footer').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary step step-' + key + '" data-step="' + key + '" onclick="sendEvent(\'#creationModal\', ' + key + ')">Continue</button>');


  });
});

sendEvent = function() {
  $('#creationModal').trigger('next.m.2');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/multi-step-modal.js"></script>



<button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-success-outline top10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#creationModal" id="btnSubmit">Create</button>


<div id='modalDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz check this https://jsfiddle.net/bmccovqp/

actually, we need to re-execute the  `multi-step-modal.js` also need to increase the step value by 1

```
function load_js()
   {
      var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= 'https://www.ngzhian.com/multi-step-modal/multi-step-modal.js';
      head.appendChild(script);
   }
```

call this function just after appending the dynamic html

Comment: Are you there??

Comment: can you help me on chat? I'm very close to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

keep all modal related divs in html only and then populate body dynamically

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"></div>
<div class="modal-step-body"></div>
<div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you help me on chat? I'm very close to the solution.